# ion-footer with input tag and two icons

Tags: html, css, ionic-framework, input, ionicons

I have a styling problem with ionic. I try to make an input box similar to WhatsApp. The problem is to get two icons as buttons in ion-input to the right side. Now, both are on the same spot and overlapped.
This is my current code:

```
  <ion-footer>
    <ion-item lines="none">
      <ion-input placeholder="Nachricht" class="message-eingabe" autoGrow="true" rows="1" maxlength="150"
        [(ngModel)]="msg">
        <ion-button class="buttonright" fill="clear">
          <ion-icon slot="end" class="rand" name="attach-outline"></ion-icon>
        </ion-button>
        <ion-button class="buttonright" fill="clear">
          <ion-icon slot="end" class="rand" name="camera"></ion-icon>
        </ion-button>
      </ion-input>
      <ion-icon name="send">
      </ion-icon>
    </ion-item>
  </ion-footer>
```

and CSS:

```
.buttonright {position: absolute; top: 0; right: 0;}
```

I like that ion-input starts on the left side, include both icons as buttons for attachment and camera. In addition the written text goes under the icons. Thats another problem. After ion-input there should be the "send"-button on the right side but not in ion-input.
Hope someone can help..

Comment: Wrap your input and icons inside ion-items. 
`<ion-item>
<ion-input></ion-input>
<ion-icon slot="end" name="send-outline"></ion-icon>
</ion-item>`

Comment: But it is inside an ion-item. It just wasn't formatted well, so I modified the code a bit.

Comment: use Slots attributes on buttons.

Answer (score 0):

Try this Code:

```
<ion-footer>
  <ion-toolbar>
    <ion-item lines="none">
      <ion-input type="text" placeholder="Message" autocomplete="on" autocorrect="on"></ion-input>
      <ion-button fill="clear" slot="end">
        <ion-icon icononly name="attach-outline"></ion-icon>
      </ion-button>
      <ion-button fill="clear" slot="end">
        <ion-icon icononly name="send-outline"></ion-icon>
      </ion-button>
    </ion-item>
  </ion-toolbar>
</ion-footer>
```

Comment: I changed it a bit but now it's looking good. Thank you!